# R: ANOVA with drop1 function fails for within factors

Tags: r, anova

I'm using the drop1 function for type III sum of squares in ANOVA.  This works fine for between factors but fails when I add in a within factor. Does anyone know where my mistake is? thanks.

```
# this work fine 
datafilename="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PNHSBMUdPnB_mnP_WrcxYYiwCwN8KHL2Q57KoAoWdAY/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv"
data.ex2=read.csv(datafilename,header=1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)                                   
aov.ex2 = aov(value~Treat*Gender,data=data.ex2  )         

drop1(aov.ex2,.~.,test="F")

## however adding within factors fails

aov.ex3 = aov(value~Treat*Gender*Region  +Error(ID/(Region))+(Gender*Treat)    ,data=data.ex2  )  
# summary works 
summary (aov.ex3)
# but drop1 funcion fails 
drop1(aov.ex3,.~.,test="F")
```

Comment: I can't download your data for some reason. But have you tried converting your factor to multiple dummy variables?

Comment: Huh, I thought R was allergic to type III sums of squares and its immune system would cause it to break out in a rash.

Comment: @SamPassmore Hmm.. the download is working on my end. And yes, thanks for the suggestion, I just tried dummy coding it but its still giving the same error ;(